# forward declaration using extern (in context of C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, extern, forward-declaration, linkage

I was confused whether to use extern for forward declarations of functions in C. The scenario is each function is in separate .c/.cpp file. I understood from going through this question - [External linkage of const in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322282/external-linkage-of-const-in-c) , that if all are .c files I should not use extern for forward declaration irrespective of whether the function is defined in same file or not.

But I would like to know more about this when to explicitly use extern for forward declarations (I think when the function being forward declared is defined in a different language than calling one, extern would be required), and any caveats to be aware of.

Comment: Functions are `extern` by default, you can use or omit this keyword from a forward declaration as you wish, the meaning doesn't change.

Comment: @n.m. using extern, the compiler ignores signature, I mean type checking is not done. So, it should not be used when not required.

Comment: "the compiler ignores signature" Wrong. Who told you so?

Comment: @n.m. I am sorry, I misunderstood...

Comment: "the compiler ignores signature" (perceived) problem happens when you make a forward declaration using extern inside a c file.  The compiler is actually doing exactly what you ask, but your extern declaration may not match the actual function declaration in another file. The compiler doesn't check (and the linker doesn't either). This is why we place forward declarations in header files, rather than sprinkling them randomly across c files. That said: does `extern` in a c file modify the declation, or is it the default?, and why do people keep trying to do this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C language there's such thing as `extern inline` which has a special meaning and in which an explicit `extern` makes a difference.

Other than that, there's never any point in specifying an explicit `extern` in functon declarations, since functions in C and C++ always have external linkage by defualt.

The matter of "different language" is probably about such things as `extern "C"`, but that's a completely different contruct from plain `extern`.

Comment: Thank you, that was what confused me. I mixed extern function declaration with extern "C" usage, and wanted to know when extern matters wrt function declarations.

Comment: Does a function declaration in block scope make a difference: i.e `void f() { extern void g(); }`?

Answer (score 5):

> I think when the function being forward declared is defined in a different language than calling one, extern would be required.

I should warn you that your question is poorly phrased.  I'm pretty sure you're interested in when to use

```
extern "C" int foo(int);
```

in C++, but I'm not sure, and I have to hope I'm not wasting my time.

Let's distinguish between compiler and linker.  I'm leaving out some details, but nothing that affects the answer to your question.

A *forward declaration* is used by the compiler.  In declaring the function, you give the compiler information about how it is used.  You declare function *F*, and when the compiler runs across *F* being used, it knows what to do.  (In the K&R days, in the absence of a declaration the compiler used defaults, sometimes leading to hilarious results.  So now they're mandatory in both C and C++.)

Usually a forward declaration of a function is a *functional prototype*: it provides the parameter types.  In C, that's not strictly necessary.  You may write

```
int foo();
```

which tells the compiler `foo` is a function returning `int`, but not what parameters it takes.  It then becomes your responsibility to get those right, because the compiler cannot check.

An `extern` declaration -- whether of a function or a variable -- notifies the compiler of a symbol and its type, and says the definition will be provided by another module.  The compiler leaves a placeholder for the linker to fill later.

If you look at the **getopt**(3) man page, for example, you'll see `optarg` is declared `extern`; it's defined in the C runtime library, but you can use it because it's been declared.

Now we come to the linker, and the `extern "C"` of C++.

To the linker, a module exposes symbols.  Global variables and functions not declared `static` have *external linkage*, meaning they can be used by other modules.

In C, there's a 1:1 correspondence between function names and external symbols.  The name is the symbol.  For example, **getopt**(3) has a symbol of the same name in the C standard library, libc:

```
$ nm -g $(find /usr/lib/ -name libc.a) 2>/dev/null | grep 'T getopt' 
0000000000001620 T getopt
0000000000000000 T getopt_long
0000000000000040 T getopt_long_only
```

In C++, the name is not the symbol.  A C++ function can be overloaded; the same name can represent different functions taking different parameters.  The compiler constructs a symbol that encodes the parameter types.  Compare:

```
$ echo 'int foo(int foo) { return foo * foo; }' > a.c && cc  -c a.c && nm a.o
0000000000000000 T foo
$ echo 'int foo(int foo) { return foo * foo; }' > a.C && c++ -c a.C && nm a.o
0000000000000000 T _Z3fooi
```

The encoding of the symbol name is often called *name mangling*.  **nm**(1) has a demangling feature:

```
$ echo 'int foo(int foo) { return foo * foo; }' > a.C && c++ -c a.C && nm -C a.o
0000000000000000 T foo(int)
```

Note that the parameter type appears next to the name.

In C++, `extern "C"` declares or defines the function as a C function.  Here's a definition:

```
$ echo 'extern "C" int foo(int foo) { return foo * foo; }' > a.C && c++ -c a.C && nm a.o
0000000000000000 T foo
```

- In a declaration, it tells the compiler that the function is defined elsewhere, and to *use* a C symbol.
- In a definition, it tells the compiler to *emit* a C symbol, i.e. not mangle the name, so that the function can be used by other C modules.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for writing such a thorough answer James. I'm writing some embedded code and having a c++ function called from assembly and this helped!

Answer (score 2):

Functions have external linkage by default, which means that

```
extern int foo(void);
```

and

```
int foo(void);
```

have *exactly the same meaning*.  This is true for *all* function declarations, except those involving `static` in some way.

In particular, the presence or absence of `extern` has *no effect* on type checking, and whether or not the function is defined in a different language is irrelevant.