# Why does writing main; in C give a segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The following is my demo.c file:

```
main;
```

On compiling this gcc gives a warning:

> demo.c:1:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
>   [enabled by default]

Running ./a.out gives a Segmentation Fault:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Is it because, (1) main is not defined anywhere and we are trying to execute it and (2) we are using an imperative statement outside any function, so it can't execute.

In either case, I still don't understand why it should throw a segfault.

Update: It might look similar to [Is ‘int main;’ a valid C/C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777071/is-int-main-a-valid-c-c-program), but this is different, as not using any identifier, compiles the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is ‘int main;’ a valid C/C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777071/is-int-main-a-valid-c-c-program)

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is formally illegal in standard C (it is generally "non-compilable"). The diagnostic message you received was intended to tell you exactly that.

However, your compiler apparently accepted it and interpreted it is some implementation-specific way. Apparently it interpreted that `main` as a definition for an `int` variable with external linkage (legacy K&R C-specific behavior). It created an object file that exports a single external symbol `main` (likely mangled in some implementation-specific way). Later linker registered that `main` as your program's entry point.

When you attempt to run your executable, loader passes control to the location of that `main` variable, mistakenly believing that this is program's entry point. The program crashes, since there's no valid executable code at that location. Or, more likely, it is data execution prevention that causes the program to crash.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Linkers are very simple-minded programs.  C++ type-safe linkage helps a lot — but C++ linkers aren't simple-minded any more.